# EF Core 2.2.6 Mapping Oracle Pacakge Function

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to map oracle pacakage scalar function to a field in C# as described here[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0][1]

the only issue I am having is EF core Genereats a statement where function name with package name is surrounded by double qotes like this "PackageName.FunctionName" which is not recognised by oracle
as correct format would PackageName.FunctionName or "PackageName"."FunctionName"

Comment: Does code work under other conditions?  Just checking because there are a lot of reasons for code not working and I'm suspecting other reasons for the failure.

Comment: yes rest of the code works fine

Comment: So some Oracle Queries work and other do not?

Comment: only statement that includes a function mapping dont work

Comment: Three things have to be consistent 1) The methods being used 2) The version of Core 3) The driver being used for the connection.  Youo can't be using Core 3.1 and using methods from Core 2.2.  A lot of things changed in Core.  See : https://medium.com/@toanbach/migrate-asp-net-core-2-2-system-to-asp-net-core-3-1-ca56e95f67bc